# [MacOS][Firefox]: <button> fails in :focus pseudo class

Tags: css, macos, firefox, safari, focus

How to use **:focus** pseudo class on a `<button>` or `<input>` in **Firefox**?!
It works with all browsers except **Firefox** & **Safari** on **MacOS**

**Note**: it works with **Keyboard[tab]** navigation but no mouse click.

```css
button:focus {
  border: 2px solid red
}
```

```html
<button tabindex="1">click</button>
```

Comment: Works well for me in FF.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't mention MacOS, so working with u on MacOS or Windows?

Comment: I am on Windows

Comment: Yeah, it's working on Windows not MacOS :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this for **FF** and **Safari**

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { border : 2px solid red; }
```

Comment: No, it didn't. Very strange to have such thing on MacOS! I'm wondering if there is any opened issues/tickets in FF!

Comment: try `-webkit-focus` or `-webkit-focus-inner` and see if it works on FF or Safari

Comment: Nothing, `-webkit-` it least for `Safari`  but nothing also.